# How to justify the text in LaTex reports?

Tags: alignment, justification

I am writing the reviewer response for the thesis report. I am keeping every comment under \begin{flushleft}..\end{flushleft}. The reason behind this is that no indentation is needed to start the comment question and reviewer response on the next line. The comments are getting left justified. However, the justification of line is missing, due to which it does not look good. Can anyone please suggest on how to correct it? The MWC is attached herewith.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, showtrims]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow}

\geometry{a4paper, top=1.5cm, left=2.0cm, right=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm, includehead, includefoot}

\begin{document}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \textbf{4.} \textit{random randomly random random random random random random randomlyrandom random randomly random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random?}
    \end{flushleft}

    \begin{flushleft}
        \textbf{Response:}
    \end{flushleft}
    random randomly random random random random random random randomlyrandom random randomly random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random?
\end{document}
```

Attaching the screenshot of the result.[image]

Comment: Is the non-zero paragraph indentation the main reason for using `flushleft`?

Comment: I am sorry but I could not understand the term 'non-zero paragraph'. Please kindly explain.

Comment: @SaurabhKumarPandey: A complete minimal working example including your preamble would be much better for diagnostics purposes.

Comment: @MarianG. I have edited the example as per your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: justification is the default the only purpose of `flushleft` is to disable justification and give a ragged margin. Simply delete those environments. perhaps you are looking for `\usepackage{parskip}` to mark paragraphs with a vertical space rather than indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a `flushleft` environment, `\raggedright` is in effect *and* the first line of each paragraph is *not indented*. I take it that you wish to achieve the second effect but not the first. If that's the case, all you need to do is (a) get rid of the `flushleft` wrappers and issue the instruction

```
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
```

A full MWE:

[image]

Do please note that if the first line of each paragraph is *not* indented, it can become difficult for your readers to notice when some paragraph ends and the next one begins. Thus, when `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` is in effect, it's also customary to set the amount of extra vertical whitespace between paragraphs (governed by the parameter `\parskip` to a non-zero amount, such as `0.5\baselineskip`.

Loading the `parskip` package, as already suggested by David Carlisle in a comment, takes care of modifying `\parindent` and `\parskip` simultaneously.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, showtrims]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.0cm,
          hmargin=2.0cm,  includehead, includefoot}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Non-zero paragraph indentation}
\textbf{4.} \textit{random randomly random random random random random random randomlyrandom random randomly random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random?}

\textbf{Response:}
random randomly random random random random random random randomlyrandom random randomly random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random?

\subsubsection*{Zero paragraph indentation}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % <-- new

\textbf{4.} \textit{random randomly random random random random random random randomlyrandom random randomly random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random?}

\textbf{Response:}
random randomly random random random random random random randomlyrandom random randomly random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random random?
\end{document}
```